# For loop gives unexpected result

Tags: jquery, html

I am unable to understand the behavior of for loop.
jquery:

```
 $('#btnTest').on("click", function () {

            var thumbUrl = "http:localhost/File/Modules/FileManager/Library/1041323042_12.jpg";
            var arrurl = thumbUrl.split("/");
            var i;
            var result;
            for (i = 0; i < arrurl.length - 1; i++) {
                result += arrurl[i] + '/';
            }
            alert(result);
 });
```

and html:

```
<input type="button" class="ThumbLink" value="Test" id="btnTest"/>
```

But `alert` gives a result:

`undefinedhttp:localhost/File/Modules/FileManager/Library/`

Where this `undefined` comes from.What is my mistake in for loop ?.Thanks.

My jsfiddle:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/xXFSe/)

Comment: Note that if the purpose of that code is to remove whatever is after the last `/` character you can do it in one line with `var result = thumbUrl.replace(/[^\/]*$/,"");`. (Or another alternative is to just replace your `for` loop with `arrurl.pop(); result=arrurl.join("/")+"/";` - i.e., remove the last element of the array before joining it back together.)

Comment: @nnnnnn I unable to understand regex so i always avoid to use it but its work perfect thanks man.

Comment: You're welcome. That regex pattern, `[^\/]*$` just says to match zero-or-more non-slash characters that are at the end of the string (and the `.replace()` replaces said characters with an empty string)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, since you're simply *appending* to `result` each time through the loop, you may want to set it initially to something *other* than `undefined`.

```
:
var result = "";
for (i = 0; i < arrurl.length - 1; i++) {
    result += arrurl[i] + '/';
}
alert(result);
:
```

Making that change to your jsfiddle link results in the correct output:

```
http:localhost/File/Modules/FileManager/Library/
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialised `result` to anything, so it will be `undefined`.

Because you are attempting to concatenate a string to `undefined`, it will `toString()` `undefined`, getting the string `"undefined"`, and will begin to concatenate to that.

You can stop this by initialising `result` to an empty string (`""`).

Answer (score 1):

You must give result an initial value:

```
var result = '';
```

Otherwise result is undefined before you concatenate the url onto it:

```
var x;
x += 'foo';  // x === 'undefinedfoo';
```

Comment: Also, in your loop it should be `i < arrurl.length`, otherwise you miss the last part of your url http://jsfiddle.net/xXFSe/2/

Answer (score 0):

declare

```
var result = "";
```

Then it will work fine :)